# Cannot import tensorflow.compat.v1 in google colab

Tags: python, tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tensorflow2.0

Since google colab no longer support version 1 of tensorflow, I been attempting to use these commands as a substitute. However, it doesn't seem to work, as "Import 'tensorflow.compat.v1' could not be resolved(reportMissingImports)"

import tensorflow.compat.v1 as tf
tf.disable_v2_behavior()

Comment: Instead you can install tensorflow 1.x in google colab using `!pip install tensorflow==1.15` and can still use it as TF 1.x in Google Colab.